# Postman asking for login credentials even though I am using a Bearer token

Tags: django-rest-framework, postman, bearer-token

I have a Django Rest Framework backend that uses a Bearer token to authenticate a user for all APIS, while testing it on POSTMAN, it displays a Django admin login form

[link to POSTMAN screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SY8S.png)

I don't understand why it's asking me to authenticate as an admin on POSTMAN.

As requested I've added urls.py for base and user:

Base urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls),
    path('user/v1/', include(('user.v1.urls', 'user'), namespace='user_v1')),
    path('second-opinion/v1/', include(('second_opinion.v1.urls', 'second-opinion'), namespace='second-opinion_v1')),
    path('utils/v1/', include(('utils.urls', 'utils'), namespace='utils_v1')),
]
```

User urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers

from user.v1.views import UserView, NotificationView, PhysicianDetailView, PhysicianProfileRequestsView, \
    ProfileInviteView, create_cognito_user, get_physician_detail


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'profile', UserView, basename='profile')
router.register(r'notification', NotificationView, basename='notification')
router.register(r'physician-detail', PhysicianDetailView, basename='physician-detail')
router.register(r'profile-request', PhysicianProfileRequestsView, basename='profile-request')
router.register(r'profile-invite', ProfileInviteView, basename='profile-invite')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    path(r'create_default_user/', create_cognito_user),
    path(r'physician/detail/<int:user_id>', get_physician_detail)
]
```

Rest Framework dictionary:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS': 'rest_framework.versioning.NamespaceVersioning',
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'utils.pagination.CustomPagination',
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'django_cognito_jwt.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'utils.custom_exception_handler.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Comment: login in browser and see the network tab , investigate how it behaves in network tab and use those request in postman instead of redirect urls

Comment: Could you add urls.py for base and users. I think your urls design is broken, so 
Django calls the admin URL no matter what URL you type.

Comment: @PDHide I'll look into that

Comment: @UtkucanBıyıklı I've added the url.py files

Comment: Can you also post your `REST_FRAMEWORK` dictionary from the `settings.py` ?

Comment: Added the REST_FRAMEWORK dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Base urls.py can you try moving `path('', admin.site.urls),` at the end of urlpatterns list instead of the very first.

Because django resolves urls in sequence and due to '' in your path for admin sites all your urls are resolving to admin page.